# Wrap all instances of word in tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a `div` containing words, like so:

```
<div class="content">
    In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis porta viverra.
</div>
```

How can I find every instance of a word, say `porta`, and wrap it with a tag, so that it becomes:

```
<div class="content">
    In condimentum facilisis <span class="highlight">porta</span>. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis <span class="highlight">porta</span> viverra.
</div>
```

I've looked at various examples, and I think this is along the right lines:

```
var elem = $(".content");
elem.text(elem.text().replace("porta", "######"));
```

But that fails every now and then, and doesn't replace every instance. I also want to stay away from using `REGEX`, as it's way too cumbersome and shouldn't be used.

Comment: 1) An example of what doesn't work would be helpful and 2) a regex shouldn't be used to parse HTML but could be very helpful for working with small strings of text (such as the contents of a node). Why the aversion?

Comment: To my previous point, regex replace example: http://regexr.com?33ukb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various cases where wrapping a word in an element becomes difficult. The trivial case is where you have simple text content:

```
<div>foo bar foo</div>
```

Then wrapping "foo" in a B element can be like:

```
div.innerHTML = div.textContent.replace(/(foo)/g,'<b>$1<\/b>');
```

However, life is more complex if you have content like:

```
<div>foo bar <span>foo</span></div>
```

where the above will remove the span (and any other element inside the div). You can deal with that by iterating over the child elements rather than using textContent (or innerText as appropriate).

There are also cases like:

```
<div>foo bar <span>f</span>oo</div>
```

You may also need to deal with word boundaries. Should "foo" be matched anywhere, or only as a whole word? Given

```
<div>myfoo bar foo</div>
```

should `myfoo` become `my<b>foo</b>` or should it be ignored? If you want to only match whole words, then you'll need something like:

```
div.innerHTML = div.textContent.replace(/(\b|\s)(foo)(\b|\s)/g,'$1<b>$2<\/b>$3');
```

This is one of those cases where you can make your life much easier by restricting the applicability of your solution (say to just the plain text content of an element), a general solution will be quite unwieldy.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
$('.content').html($('.content').html().replace(/(porta)/g,'<span class="highlight">$1</span>'));
```

See: [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mvAc/)

Comment: @Charlie see the jsFiddle Demo

Comment: This runs into some problems, however. For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/5mvAc/3/ If you have parenthesis within the highlighted text, it duplicates the parenthesis for some reason. Also, if you select something, then select something else with the original selection as a part of it, it doesn't select the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the each() function: http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$( ".content .highlight" ).each(function( ) {
   this.text().replace("porta","###");
});
```

this could to the trick...

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this solution, should work with all texts, and does not use the regex.

```
var elem = $(".content");
var ar = elem.text().split(' '), newval='';
for (var i=0; i<ar.length; i++){
    if (ar[i].indexOf("porta") == 0) {
        var partial = ar[i].split('porta');
        (partial[1]=="." || partial[1]==",") ? newval+="<div class='highlight'>porta</div>"+partial[1]+" " : newval+=ar[i]+' ';
        }
    else newval+=ar[i]+' ';
}
elem.html(newval);
```

and jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/u5RxZ/2/

Comment: This also selects more than just the text. For instance, it selects the period in the first instance.

Comment: It also selects words that include part of the word.

Comment: edited the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u5RxZ/2/ mark the word only to ignore dot and comma after the word, and if another letter ignore the whole word, you can add semicolon and colon if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

```
function highlighter = (string,val){
    String.prototype.splice = function(start, delCount, newSubStr) {
        return this.slice(0, start) + newSubStr + this.slice(start + Math.abs(delCount));
    };
    var spanBegin = "<span class='highlight'>";
    var spanEnd = "</span>";
    var search_regexp = new RegExp(val, "gi");
    var myArray;
    var indexCollection = [];
    while ((myArray = search_regexp.exec(string)) !== null) {
        indexCollection.push(myArray.index);
    }

    indexCollection.forEach(function(stringIdx,idxInCol,col){
        var offset1 = (idxInCol * (spanBegin.length + spanEnd.length));
        var offset2 = stringIdx + offset1 + val.length + spanBegin.length;
        string = string.splice((stringIdx + offset1),0,spanBegin);
        string = string.splice(offset2,0,spanEnd);
    });

    return string;
}
```

Comment: For all those looking for a neat example - This should wrap matches of the regex in a span. Enjoy.